# difference in performance in Primary Key

Tags: mysql

I have a table  with 4 columns:

```
id1 int
id2 text  or varChar
 type
 timestamp
```

The primary key is **(id1,id2,type)**
and I want to change to **(id2,id1,type)**  .

What is the difference in performance will be?Maybe it will be similar to the keys on the performance?

Comment: Keys do not perform themselves. Do you have specific SQL queries in mind?

Comment: A primary key over a TEXT column is quite unusual.

Comment: Why do you want to change it if you don't know what the effect will be?

Comment: If you want to create index on (almost) whole table what you expect to get? If index is same size as table there is no need to use index

Comment: depends on content. depends on use. depends size. depends on query. Impossible to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add such kind primary key, use a long/int value for primary key, or a sequence if your database has one.
 
And, if you want to make a column or a combination of columns to be unique, just mark it or the combination of them as unique.
And also, for columns which are not primary key, you can also add index key to it or them, if need to.

Comment: very clever recommendation

Answer (score 0):

You'll have two indexes like:
`id1`, `id2`, `type` - together(so you must use all three column in WHERE clause).

Also

**1 case(id1,id2,type)** - you can use in WHERE separate `id1`.

**2 case(id2,id1,type)** - you can use in WHERE separate `id2`.

But it's not really good practice to use several column as primary key.